# react-hook-form how to have a registered field validation happen only at a button trigger, but not at form submission?

Tags: reactjs, react-hook-form, onsubmit

Using react-hook-form V6. Let's say there is a text input "email" in my form.  My form has 2 buttons:

- The first button("save") submits the form, no validation needed. The entire form should be saved.
- The second button("verify") would validate the "email" field,  and then calls a custom function and do some other stuff.

Now for my "email" input control, I have this:

```
ref={register({
     validate: {
              validateEmail: (email) => {
                    ....
                        }
                    }
                })}
```

Then my 2nd "verify" button onClick method can trigger the email validation. All good.

But on "Save" (form submission) , I do not want validation on this "email" field. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I find the solution. Every time it seems after I posted a question, it really helps me to formulate my thoughts and guide me towards the answer.

Anyway the solution is that do not have validation tied at "register". This way "form submit" would not have the validation. Now for the 2nd button, call setError(...) when applies.

Here are 2 links that have really helped:

https://react-hook-form.com/v6/api#setError

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=raMqvE0YyIY